# Drop alpha character from serial input

Tags: arduino-uno, string

I receive strings over the serial port like so:

VLT=53.0, AMP=-30.2, AHR=-10, SOC=98, TMP=136, STS=192

I want to reduce the use of string functions with the idea of dropping all non-digits, keeping numbers dot and comma, to get this:

53.0,-30.2,-10,98,136,192

in an array and simple read [0], [1], etc.

Regular expressions would be idea, but do not exist like in PERL.
Any hint would be much appreciated.

Relevant code used:

```
    char inByte = SerialPortOne.read(); // read byte
    strRecordIn.concat(inByte);         // add byte to receive buffer
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {    // VLT, AMP, AHR, SOC
    strWord = getValue(strRecordIn, ',', i);  // get data item from RecordIn array
      strWord.remove(0, 4);           // remove field identifier (1st 3 char plus =)
      strRecordOut += ',';            // add delimiter
      strRecordOut += strWord;        // add value
      strWord = "";                   // reset strWord
    }
```

Ideally:

```
    char inByte = SerialPortOne.read(); // read byte
    if (inByte = [%d.,]+) {
      strRecordIn.concat(inByte);       // add byte to receive buffer
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to remove the letters:

```c++
#include <ctype.h>

char inByte = SerialPortOne.read();  // read byte
if (!isalpha(inByte)) {              // not letter
    strRecordIn.concat(inByte);      // add byte to receive buffer
}
```

Or you may test it for `isdigit()` and explicitly compare to `','` and
`'.'`:

```c++
if (isdigit(inByte) || inByte == '.' || inByte == ',') {
    strRecordIn.concat(inByte);      // add byte to receive buffer
}
```

C.f. the [documentation of
<ctype.h>](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__ctype.html).

Comment: Brilliant! I got lots to learn in this Arduino environment. Thank you!

Comment: @MaxG: Well, in this case it's standard C, not specific to Arduino.